# Documentation about error in callback functions of mongoose methods

Tags: javascript, mongoose, callback

I am starting to handle critical scenarios in my web-developement and up till now I just never paid much attention to the **err** in callbacks of my code, usually all I did is for example :

```
Model.find({'_id': someId}, function(err, doc) {
 if(err) console.log(err)
 else { // do business logic })
```

Problem is I have not stumbled over situations where I'd receive errors, and I want a complete account of why these erros might be throws so I can prepare my code for production scenario.

I've looked on some documentation but I can't find a complete review of why errors might be thrown, does such a resource exist ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of possible scenarios where errors can be thrown during mongodb operations by mongoose. Examples include

1.
In your case: if the id being passed to get the document isn't valid (i.e. cannot be cast to an objectId). This will probably be a developer error in which case he might be passing an invalid id to the method since usually users are not made to enter ids. To cover all possible loop holes or acting as a defensive programmer you would want to handle an error in that instance as below by return a `NOT FOUND` status with an appropriate message. The developer then check for the return object's status or message to act appropriately.

```
Model.find({'_id': someId}, function(err, doc) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
        return { 
            status: 'Not Found',
            message: 'Possible Invalid ID or Document does not exist'
        }
    }else { // do other business logic }
})
```

2. In an update scenario, a possible error may arise if id being passed to get the document and update isn't valid (i.e. cannot be cast to an objectId) OR document does not exist i.e. id does match any document. Similar approach to handling the error in point 1 may be used.
3. Other errors may also arise when doing a `DELETE` or `CREATE` in which there is the need to handle the errors.

Finally a need may arise to handle the errors as an oversight (e.g syntax) of some sort may also throw an error.

In all these, I want to add that mongoose error objects may usually be of the following form as referenced from [mongoose issues on github](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2284) (an example of an create error due to duplicate keys).

```
{
    [MongoError: insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error 
    index: mydb-api.users.$email_1  dup key: { : "my@duplicate.com" }]
    name: 'MongoError',
    code: 11000,
    err: 'insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: mydb-api.users.$email_1  dup key: { : "my@duplicate.com" }' }
}
```

Comment: These are all interesting and some I thought of. Thanks for the link, I wish there was some comprehensive list but this is a fair start.